# WiX creating a table on an existing database

Tags: sql-server, wix, wix3.8

I'm creating a plugin for an existing application and I need to add a table to the database this application is using (MSSQL-database). The problem is that I can't find any tutorial or documentation about how to do this with wix. I use msiext for the UI to retrieve the database server and the credentials to access and execute operations on the database.

I hope you can help me and if you need any additional information please ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventhough it is not the most beautifull solution i managed to get it working with an sql script tag like:

```
<sql:SqlScript Id='CreateTable' BinaryKey='CreateTable' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
```

and it creates my table.

Answer (score 1):

It is not in because it is a VERY bad idea to manipulate a database in the installer - which my and should normally not execute with permissions in the database.

You are a lot better off to follow best practices and handle database maintenance outside the application installation, as every other commercial application I have ever seen does. Generally DB updates and application updates are and should be separate.

If you HAVE To do it - execute a custom action.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, the point that i try to manipulate the database from the installer is that the plugin is running under a service-account which doesn't have the rights to create a table.

Comment: SO it needs another tool you install that can be run to set up the database. Simple like that.